# vyatta Server Reboots by itself

Tags: hardware, vyatta, 10gige

I have an issue regarding some hardware, maybe you can help me.

First, I set up a Supermicro Superserver SYS-5016I-NTF with a Intel Xeon X3470 and 4
GB of Ram  with a Hotlava Card Tambora 64G4 with Intel Chipset 82599EB and 4x10G
SPF+ ports. Installed  Vyatta community edition 6.3.
  I used it as router making BGP connections with 2 operators.
  No load at all, temp ranges normal.
  But the issue is that it reboots by itself in a ramdom way. Not very often,
once every few days.  But it is unacceptable for production purposes.

So I try to test on different hardware, and installed Vyatta community edition
6.3 on a Dell PowerEdge 2950, with  Xeon(R) E5345 @ 2.33GHz and 4 GB of Ram.
Same Vyatta configuration as Supermicro Server. With same hotlava Card model ( I
bought two of them )  Well I have reboots with this equipment as well. Same frecuency as above.

I have checked syslog  no strange logs until boot process starts to be logged. So it seems server reboot suddenly. 
I have installed latest driver for the chipset of the Hotlava card.
Servers are placed in a datacenter with UPS

So finally two things in common in both servers:

- Hotlava Card. Someone with issues with this card, or the chipset?? Could be
  it this card??
- Vyatta 6.3 community edition. I don't thing is the problem. Is a regular
  Debian with packages to glue together different services.

Or maybe is something I am missing.

Andy ideas, suggestions??

Thank you very much...

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the firmware including the BIOS, BMC, Storage, Network, and dont use these Broadcom chipsets, these a making issues, the best is to use either Intel driver, because Broadcom to fully work requires firmware, and this is not always present and working well in every Linux.
Simply you might try putting extra network card and switch off the Broadcom ones.
Hotlava also can cause a problem if it doesnt have a stable driver, so I would check the module settings etc.